# AttributeError AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor' DOCKER-MYSQL-FLASK

Tags: python, mysql, docker, flask, docker-compose

I was doing my Database homework, and I could not create a connection with my Flask app with MySQL. I'm using Docker also. My OS is Windows. Can you provide help to me? You do not need to look at the executions about cursor.execute statements. The main problem is about cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) statement. Here is the code:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get install -y pkg-config
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: cs353hw4app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: python app.py
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: cs353hw4db
    ports:
      - "8080:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.2.3
Werkzeug==2.2.3
mysqlclient
flask_mysqldb
```

app.py:

```
import re  
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors

app = Flask(__name__) 

app.secret_key = 'abcdefgh'
  
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'db'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'cs353hw4db'
mysql = MySQL(app)  

@app.route('/')

@app.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    message = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']


        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM student WHERE sname = % s AND sid = % s', (username, password, ))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        if user:              
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['userid'] = user['id']
            session['username'] = user['username']
            session['email'] = user['email']
            message = 'Logged in successfully!'
            return redirect(url_for('tasks'))
        else:
            message = 'Please enter correct email / password !'
    return render_template('login.html', message = message)


@app.route('/register', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    message = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form :
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = % s', (username, ))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            message = 'Choose a different username!'
  
        elif not username or not password or not email:
            message = 'Please fill out the form!'

        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO User (id, username, email, password) VALUES (NULL, % s, % s, % s)', (username, email, password,))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            message = 'User successfully created!'

    elif request.method == 'POST':

        message = 'Please fill all the fields!'
    return render_template('register.html', message = message)

@app.route('/tasks', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def tasks():
    return "Tasks page"

@app.route('/analysis', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def analysis():
    return "Analysis page"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

schema.sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS cs353hw4db;
USE cs353hw4db;

CREATE TABLE student(
    sid CHAR(6),
    sname VARCHAR(50), 
    bdate DATE, 
    dept CHAR(2), 
    year VARCHAR(15), 
    gpa FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY(sid)
);

CREATE TABLE company(
    cid CHAR(5), 
    cname VARCHAR(20), 
    quota INT, 
    gpa_threshold FLOAT, 
    city VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(cid)
);

CREATE TABLE apply(
    sid CHAR(6),
    cid CHAR(5), 
    PRIMARY KEY(sid,cid),
    FOREIGN KEY(sid) REFERENCES student(sid),
    FOREIGN KEY(cid) REFERENCES company(cid)
);

INSERT INTO student VALUES
    ('S101', 'Ali', '1999-07-15', 'CS', 'sophomore' ,2.92),
    ('S102', 'Veli', '2002-01-07', 'EE', 'junior' , 3.96),
    ('S103', 'Ayşe', '2004-02-12', 'IE', 'freshman' , 3.30),
    ('S104', 'Mehmet', '2003-05-23', 'CS', 'junior' , 3.07);    

INSERT INTO company VALUES
    ('C101', 'tübitak', 10, 2.50, 'Ankara'),
    ('C102', 'bist', 2, 2.80, 'Istanbul'),
    ('C103', 'aselsan', 3, 3.00, 'Ankara'),
    ('C104', 'thy', 5, 2.40, 'Istanbul'),    
    ('C105', 'milsoft', 6, 2.50, 'Ankara'),    
    ('C106', 'amazon', 1, 3.80, 'Palo Alto'),
    ('C107', 'tai', 4, 3.00, 'Ankara'); 

INSERT INTO apply VALUES
    ('S101', 'C101'),
    ('S101', 'C102'),
    ('S101', 'C104'),
    ('S102', 'C106'),
    ('S103', 'C104'),
    ('S103', 'C107'),
    ('S104', 'C102'),
    ('S104', 'C107');
```

On the docker, containers are working. However, the connection between flask and MySQL is not established, I guess. Here is the error from the browser (

```
AttributeError
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2551, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2531, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
File "/app/app.py", line 28, in login
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

Thank you in advance.